# adding event function body with lambda expression error not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, events, lambda

This is my code and it gives me error that `Not all code paths return a value` in lambda expression.

```
skdForm.onSentinelKeyWrite += (s) =>
{
    releaseSentinelData = s;
};
```

Can any body help me please?

Comment: Can you show the delegate signiture of onSentinelKeyWrite? if it has a return other then void you need to satisfy it by returning expected value

Comment: yes its deligate is : delegate string delSentinelKeyWrite(string data);

Comment: As you can see it expects you to return a string from your lambda

Comment: just add return string.Empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, `delSentinelKeyWrite(string data)` must return a string:

```
skdForm.onSentinelKeyWrite += (s) =>
{
   releaseSentinelData = s;
   return s;
};
```